# How can I change the font of all equations?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations, amsmath

I'd like to change my default font style in all equations of one document, not just single equation.

I guess I am using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}`, which may be related to font setting.

Which font I want to change into is like

[image]

but now is

[image]

I am using pdfLaTex in TeXworks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `{\boldsymbol\beta}`:

[image]

Comment: thanks. but the style 'bold' is not an issue here, but just font style.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand very well what you require. Everything typeset in boldface? Or use another font that pleases you more? It's not very clear from your images.

Comment: Here is a sample of three different math fonts: `fourier`, based on Adobe Utopia, completed by `heuristica` to have optical smallcaps, superior and inferior figures,  and oldstyle figures

Answer (score 1):

The Keplerfonts for text and math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    y_{it}
    &= \mathbf{x'_{\mathit{it}}}\bm{\beta} + \mathbf{z'_\mathit{i}} \bm{\alpha} + \varepsilon_\mathit{it} \\
    &= \mathbf{x'_{\mathit{it}}}\bm{\beta} + c_i + \varepsilon_\mathit{it}
\end{align*}

\blindtext
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the `bm` package for the bold greek. The font looks like `stix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stix,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    y_{it}
    &= \mathbf{x'}_{it}\bm{\beta} + \mathbf{z'}_i \bm{\alpha} + \varepsilon_{it} \\
    &= \mathbf{x'}_{it}\bm{\beta} + c_i + \varepsilon_{it}
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: bold is not my question, but font style is good.
how can i install the font? 
just adding \usepackage{stix} is not working.

Comment: @KENgerine In TL2014 it is simply `tlmgr install stix`, on Ubuntu you do `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra`, on MikTeX open the package manager and search for `stix`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of three different math fonts:

- `fourier`, based on Adobe Utopia, completed by `heuristica` to have optical smallcaps, superior and inferior figures,  and oldstyle figures.
- MinionPro, based on Adobe's Minion Pro opentype font that comes with Adobe Reader.
- mathdesign's `garamond` option, based on URW Garamond No 8, completed by `garamondx` to have smallcaps (in regular, boldface, italic and boldface italic), oldstyle figures and superior figures.

Just comment and uncomment the relevant font loading lines in the following code to obtain the examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% for Utopia
%\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{heuristica}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% for Minion Pro
%\usepackage{MinionPro}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% for URW Garamond
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    y_{it}
    &= \mathbf{x'_{\mathit{it}}}\bm{\beta} + \mathbf{z'_\mathit{i}} \bm{\alpha} + \varepsilon_\mathit{it} \\
    &= \mathbf{x'_{\mathit{it}}}\bm{\beta} + c_i + \varepsilon_\mathit{it}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Fourier:

[image]

MinionPro:

[image]

URW Garamond:

[image]